# how used css for adjuste text post by user

Tags: php, html, css

// code

`<div class="allpost">hello world </div>`

// code css for class allpost

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 300px; 
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

// problem display post

```
hello\r\world
```

i want delete `\r` 
 i don't know how used css for professional post by user 
 i have a website forum

// code php

```
<div id="result">
<?php 

$stmt = $connect->query('SELECT post FROM publications ORDER BY date_post DESC ');


while($row=$stmt->fetch() )
{
    ?>
    <div class="allpost">  
<?php 
    echo json_encode ($row['post']) ;
    ?>
    </div>

<?php 
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: how is this related to php??

Comment: Can you post your php please

Comment: i  have not problem for code php

Comment: question edited

Comment: why do you `json_encode` the post??

Comment: just error to copy ,  
i have not problem for code php

Comment: if this is not the real code, then _show the real code_!

Comment: also, did you check what you have in your database? Is the `\r\` there already? Then check how you save the post.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your database has the special chars encoded. Try filtering them out with something like this:

```
$row = str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $row);
```

Also, why the json_enconde there?... and what does any of this has to do with CSS?